# How to solve AWS Elastic Beanstalk error : 100.0 % of the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I tried to deploy my Django project to EB, but keep on getting the health as "Sever" with this error :

> - 100.0 % of the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx.
> - Process default has been unhealthy for 1 hour 19 minutes (Target.ResponseCodeMismatch).
> - Following services are not running: web.

When I click the URL of the environment, I get an error saying "502 Bad Gateway : nginx/1.16.1". 
Also I'm using python 3.7.
I'm not sure if this information is sufficient, so please do let me know if you need any further information. 
Or could it possibly be a DB error?

Comment: When you go to url/ip of instance directly, does your app work? Also do you use single instance or load-balance environment?

Comment: Target.ResponseCodeMismatch means the health checks did not return an expected HTTP code. Applies only to Application Load Balancers and Gateway Load Balancers.